# Swift 3: cannot convert value of type 'String.Index' to expected argument type Range (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')

Tags: string, swift3, swift-playground

I'm trying to replace a substring with another substring but I'm getting this error:

```
 cannot convert value of type 'String.Index' (aka 'String.CharacterView.Index') to expected argument type 'Range<String.Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')
```

Here is my Code:

```
// This are the position of the substrings:
let rangeOne = strToSort.index(strToSort.startIndex, offsetBy: (i-1))
let rangeTwo = strToSort.index(strToSort.startIndex, offsetBy: (i))

Here is where I try to make the replacement:


strToSort = strToSort.replacingCharacters(in: rangeOne, with: strToSort.substring(with: rangeTwo))
```

But I'm getting this error:

[image]

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or a work around this?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: You want to change `EHLLOAGAIN` to `HELLOAGAIN` ?

Comment: `var chars = "EHLLOAGAIN".characters.map{String($0)}`
`swap(&chars[0], &chars[1])`

Comment: @LeoDabus, but how you do it programmatically. what I mean is if switch substring in position x with substring at position y?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code like this

```
var strToSort = "HELLOAGAIN"
let rangeOne = strToSort.index(strToSort.startIndex, offsetBy: (2))
let rangeTwo = strToSort.index(strToSort.startIndex, offsetBy: (3))
let stringRange = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: rangeOne, upper: rangeTwo))
strToSort = strToSort.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: strToSort)
print(strToSort)
```

As in your code there is no range defined and the method
**replacingCharacters**
 require argument of type 
   `Range<String.Index>`
 and you are providing type `String.Index` is incorrect so you are getting error.

If you want to replace occurrences of string like H with E you can use different `String` method like

```
let aString: String = "HELLO"
let newString = aString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("H", withString: "E", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

Comment: How can manage the range if I want to replace the H for E. For example EHLLOAGAIN?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is replace substring base in the position of the string not in the value.